# How to handle global jquery in external components in jest

Tags: jquery, webpack, jestjs

I need to test react components that have a dependency to some legacy code that needs a global jquery instance. With our webpack/karma/mocha setup we could set this like:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({'$':'jquery' })
```

is there a way to do the same for jest?

I'm totally aware of mocking out the dependencies in my tests but I'm looking for a more general solution. So is there a way to use Jest with webpack to have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just overwrite it like this:

```
const ajax = jest.fn((options) => {
  if (/\/successPath/.test(options.url)) {
    return options.success('someData', '', { status: 200 });
  }
  return options.error({ status: 404, responseText: 'someError' });
});
global.$ = { ajax: ajax };
```

So just replace it with a mock that just hold the function you need to use in your module.